# Where did Erasmus get his Byzantine text(s) and what connections did the Waldenses have if any?

Tags: bible-translation, manuscript

Of the Byzantine texts that Erasmus had at his disposal, where did he come by them?
Also, did the Waldenses provide any either directly or indirectly?

Comment: Try: www.insightoftheking.com/erasmus-greek-new-testament.html

Comment: thanks - interesting mention of Aldus Manutius the Italian printer while in the northern Italian city of Bologna.  Manutius, the article above claims, gave Erasmus Byzantine manuscripts.  Very interesting.  Now I'm wondering if we can find where Manutius got them, as I dont think he was directly associated with the Waldenses, yet he was located in the general area where they were.

Answer (score 2):

About the middle of the 15th century a series of events began to transform Europe, leading up to Erasmus and his translation work. These events had to do with Greek manuscripts of the New Testament 'exploding' on to the scholastic scene, as this book explains:

> "The capture of Constantinople by the Turks (1453) caused the flight
> of learned Greeks to the West. These carried with them priceless
> manuscripts containing the old Greek literature, long forgotten in the
> darkened West. Some Greek Professors were teaching in the Universities
> of Italy the language which gave the key to these treasures of
> knowledge, and from there to Oxford the study of Greek spread
> rapidly... but the restoration and publication of the text of the
> Greek New Testament had more powerful results than were produced by
> the recovery of any other of the restored literature...
>
> By the end of the 15th century 98 complete editions of the Latin Bible
> had been printed, and much larger numbers of Portions. The Archbishop
> of Mainz renewed the edicts forbidding the use of German Bibles, but
> in about 12 years 14 editions of the German Bible had been printed...
> **These were all taken from the same text as the Testament found in the abbey at Tepl**...
>
> In all the groups of distinguished scholars and printers forming over
> Europe, Erasmus became the best known scholar... His greatest work was
> the publication of the Greek Testament, with a new Latin translation."
> *The Pilgrim Church*, E.H. Broadbent, pp.113-4, Pickering Classic, first published 1931, reprint 2985.

***The text in question might be that identified with the abbey at Tepl*** (perhaps bearing that name? I don't know.) ***Any connection with the Waldenses?*** That group seem to be so connected with myriad other groups, it's hard to say. The name was given to believers in Alpine valleys. They were also known as the Vaudous, the Leonists, and they prepared the way for the Hussite movement. The Waldenses were connected with the Bogomils, the Albigenses, Wycliff and Huss, and had connections in Bohemia and Austria. Trying to get a clear line of inquiry to tease out any connection would be a mammoth task, it seems to me. So - pass, on that one!